# akka scheduler hang on play application reload

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

When working locally play framework reload on every code change. In my case the app hang. I found out when debugging, that akka scheduler is stuck executing one of the Runnables.

```
class SchedulerModule extends AbstractModule {

  def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[MyScheduler]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}

@Singleton
class MyScheduler @Inject()(asyncCache: AsyncCache){    
   actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(1 minutes, 1 minutes, new Validation(){ override def validate() = //do some io operation})
}

abstract class Validation extends Runnable{
  def validate(): Future[Check]
  def name: String

  override def run(): Unit = {
    Try(Await.result(validate(), timeout)) match {
    case Success(None) =>
    case Failure(e) => Logger.error(errorMessage + s"$name failed!", e)
  }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
Is it wrong to block inside a Runnable?
What am I missing?

Here is where the application is stuck (taken from a thread dump):

```
"application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3" #95 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fe1ebb9f000 nid=0x930b waiting on condition [0x0000700002c41000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007ad483058> (a scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$CompletionLatch)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:208)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
    at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread$$anon$3.block(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:167)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3640)
    at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread.blockOn(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:165)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.blockOn(BatchingExecutor.scala:106)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
```

Thank you!